# How to trigger javax validations manually via reflection or any other way?

Tags: java, spring, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I am using `validation-api-2.0.1.Final` and `hibernate-validator-6.0.13.Final`. I would like to do validation for the below case,

I have created a custom validation to validate `List<Map<String,Object>>`

**BookInfo.java**

```
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(
        validatedBy = {BookInfoValidator.class}
)
public @interface BookInfo {
    String message() default "Should not be empty";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**BookInfoValidator.java**

```
public class BookInfoValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidateUserInfo, List<Map<String, Object>>> {

    private final ContentRepositoryClient contentRepository;

    public ValidateUserInfoValidator(ContentRepositoryClient contentRepository) {
        this.contentRepository = contentRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidateUserInfo constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(List<Map<String,Object>> map, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        //In the list of Map the key will be "text,email,date etc etc" based on the key i would like to
        //validate with the proper validation constraints
        //ex) for Email invoke javax.validation.constraints.Email.class from validation-api
        //I am not sure how to manually invoke the validation annotations.
        return false;
    }
}
```

**BookInfoView.java**

```
class BookInfoView {
        @BookInfo
        private List<Map<String, Object>> bookInfos;
    }
```

In the list of Map the key will be "text, email, date etc". Based on the key I would like to validate with the proper validation constraints
exception for Email invoke `javax.validation.constraints.Email.class` from validation-api. I am not sure how to manually invoke the validation annotations.

Any hint or help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

> I am not sure how to manually invoke the validation annotations.

I am answering above quoted lines. **Yes**, it is possible to invoke validation programmatically and in case of validation failures you will receive all failure messages in a set. Below are the steps to do the same:

1. Build `ValidatorFactory`
2. Get hold of a `Validator` instance from `ValidatorFactory`
3. Perform the validation using `validate()` method
4. Process the validation result `constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage()`

Show some code, below is the code snippet for all four steps mentioned above:

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<BookInfoView>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(bookInfoViewObj);
assertEquals( "Should not be empty", constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage() );
```

Hibernate Validator framework provides various other capabilities to validate one or more entities and then process the result. Better you have look at [official document](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-validating-bean-constraints).

Comment: I know how to invoke the custom validation and of course, we can invoke any bean-validation like this. But my question is completely different. I would like to access "NotNull" or "NotEmpty" or "Email" inside BookinfoValidator "isValid" method. Could you please read the commented lines inside BookInfoValidator

Comment: @VelNaga my question is, the object(which needs to be validated) which is present inside the map is already annotated with `@NotNull`, `@NotEmpty` and `@Email` or not?

Comment: Nope it’s just a list of map  ....check BookInfoView class I’ve mentioned

Answer (score 2):

There's no 'nice' way of accessing validator implementations for constraints (email , not null etc.). While you could create instances of those validators and store them in your `BookInfoValidator` you would need to do a lot of additional work. As for each validator its `ConstraintValidator#initialize()` method. While in case of simple constraints like `@NotNull` there's actually noting to initialize, the same check can easily be performed without this validator. And in case of a more complex ones like `@Email` you would need to create your own proxy class for the annotation so you could properly initialize the constraint validator.

With that said I would suggest to write a wrapper class for your `Map`, something like:

```
public class BookInfoWrapper {
    private final Map<String, Object> data;

    public BookInfoWrapper(Map<String, Object> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @NotNull
    public Map<String, Object> getUser(){
        return (Map<String, Object>) data.get( "user" );
    }

    @Email
    public String getEmail(){
        return Objects.toString(( getUser() ).get( "email" ));
    }

    // and any other constraints you need
}
```

And then convert your list of maps to these wrappers before validation.

I can also see that you have a repository in your validator, hence I think that you might want to derive rules "dynamically". In such case you might want to check out the [programmatic API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-programmatic-api) provided by Hibernate Validator. Using it you should be able to build the rules you need based on the data retrieved from the database. But still you would need to wrap the maps first.

To summarize it all, sadly there's no nice and easy solution for your particular case yet. We are working on a validation of free form objects but it'll take us some time to be able to release it. Hence I would suggest that you should either

- write the validation checks on your own in your `BookInfoValidator` without using built-in constraints.
- use a wrapper approach described above.